# How to run query in comonent in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I want to run query in component file in cakephp, but it shows fatal error, when i do this in controller it works perfectly fine, but i want to do it in component.

```
 function product_check(){

 $this->User = ClassRegistry::init('User');
 $this->UserNode = ClassRegistry::init('UserNode');
 $this->ProductsUserNode = ClassRegistry::init('ProductsUserNode');

    $conditionss = array(
        # http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html
        'OR' => array(
            array('ProductsUserNode.'. NODE_ID => $this->Auth->user(NODE_ID)),
            array('ProductsUserNode.'. NODE_ID => $this->Auth->user(NODE_IDX)),
        ),
    );

     $productcheck = $this->User->UserNode
                                ->ProductsUserNode
                                ->find(
                                    'first'
                                    , array(
                                            'conditions' => $conditionss
                                    )   
                                );

     $active = $productcheck['ProductsUserNode']['is_active'];
    if ($active == "0")
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('You Are Deactived For This Product'); 
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'events','action'=>'view_dashboard'));
    } 


}
```

but it show this error

```
Fatal Error
Error: Call to a member function user() on a non-object
```

how can i do solve this? Thanks in Advance

Comment: I have edited my answer check it out!

Comment: what cake version are you using? you cant have 1.3 and 2.x :)

Comment: I am using 2.x right now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't specify that your component uses the `Auth` component. You can do it with the following snippet:

```
public $components = array('Auth');
```

See also [Using other Components in your Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#using-other-components-in-your-component)

Answer (score 0):

try by Loading the User model in product_check() by

```
  $this->ModelName = ClassRegistry::init('ModelName');
```

in your case it is User , this should idealy work, just make sure you have :

```
  model : User.php
```

and table as

```
users
```

hope will help you!